# PostSharp support on M1 Macs (linux-arm64)

Tags: arm64, postsharp, apple-m1

I've recently started using PostSharp for caching on a .NET 5 app and it's working phenomenally on my 2015 MacBook Pro (Intel). However, I just recently got an M1 Mac Mini, which has Apple's own M1 chipset (linux-arm64), and, unfortunately, I am not able to build the solution anymore. The error I'm getting is:

```
#19 8.572 /root/.nuget/packages/postsharp/6.9.8/build/PostSharp.targets(381,5): error : This version of PostSharp does not support linux-arm64 runtime. [/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
#19 8.586
#19 8.586 Build FAILED.
#19 8.586
#19 8.586 /root/.nuget/packages/postsharp/6.9.8/build/PostSharp.targets(381,5): error : This version of PostSharp does not support linux-arm64 runtime. [/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
#19 8.586     0 Warning(s)
#19 8.586     1 Error(s)
#19 8.586
#19 8.586 Time Elapsed 00:00:08.05
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build -c Release -o /app]: exit code: 1
```

My current project file indicates the following dependencies:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Application\Application.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <PackageReference Include="PostSharp" Version="6.9.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="PostSharp.Patterns.Caching" Version="6.9.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="PostSharp.Patterns.Caching.Redis" Version="6.9.8" />
        ...
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It looks like there isn't a linux-arm64 build for PostSharp on Nuget. They do indicate support for macOS 10.14 in their docs [here](https://doc.postsharp.net/requirements#development), but not anything about support for M1 Macs.

Is there a way to get a linux-arm64 build of PostSharp (even if I have to build from source myself)?

Comment: PostSharp uses unsafe code, which is not easy to port to ARM64. If it is possible to install the X64 version of .NET and run it under Rosetta 2, I would advise doing that. PostSharp's MSBuild files would then detect the runtime and should be able to use it.

Comment: So, I won't be able to build a solution that uses PostSharp?  :(